# Using square bracket in antlr to parse sql

Tags: antlr4

I want a parser for a string like sql column

```
[type](max)
```

where type could be VARCHAR | NVARCHAR

```
lexer:
VARCHAR:             'VARCHAR';
NVARCHAR:            'NVARCHAR';
LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET  '[';
RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET ']';
MAX                  'MAX';

parser:
LEFT_SQUARE_BRAKCET? (VARCHAR | NVARCHAR) '(' MAX ')' RIGHT_SQUARE_BRAKCET?
```

but doesn't work

if I use

```
(VARCHAR | NVARCHAR) '(' MAX ')'
```

then the string

```
type(max)
```

it's working.

I think that [ is recognized as a special character.

Answer (score 0):

```
VARCHAR:             'VARCHAR';
NVARCHAR:            'NVARCHAR';
LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET  '[';
RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET ']';
MAX                  'MAX';

sample: LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET (VARCHAR | NVARCHAR) RIGHT_SQUARE_BRAKCET '(' MAX ')';
```

Use sample as your parser rule.  This should parse your input as desired.

Your main problem is that the `RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET` token was not in the correct place in your parser rule.

I changed the brackets to be required (removed the `?`) as it does not seem you intend them to be optional (which the `?` does).